# Writing a custom PSD file with smart objects

Tags: java, photoshop, psd

I am working on a custom application that can load an existing PSD file, 
modify it (add a layer), and write it to a new PSD file. All existing layers 
are also written to the new PSD file.

This all works fine with normal layers, but I have a problem with layers that contain smart objects..
If I open the new PSD file in Photoshop, and click on a layer with a smart object, Photoshop crashes...

So there is a bug somewhere in my app. but it is a bit hard to find, because 
the PSD file format is not well documented (I can find almost nothing about smart objects), 
and Photoshop does not seem to have an error log.

My configuration is as follows:

- Windows 8.1 (64 bit)
- Adobe Photoshop CC 2014

Has anyone got any experience with this and does anyone know if Photoshop has a logging function?
So I can use the information in the log to find my programming error...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really are asking how to turn on logging in Photoshop, I believe SuperUser is a better place to ask. If you want help with the programming part, you have come to the right place, but nobody will be able to help without some more detail (code).